# Are the keys in TFRecords required?

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I am converting LISA Traffic Sign dataset to TFRecord,

and wonder if I need to fill out all keys fields with the fake values when information is unavailable.

Or I can ignore the fields, such as view/truncated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [using_your_own_dataset.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md) provided by Tensorflow

other fields are not used in the model if you use Tensorflow object detection API.

Please let me know if any question.